# Getting started with WPF & Orchestra

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, catel, orchestra

I'm working on creating my first WPF application, whereas I have only used WinForms in the past.  I've familiarized myself with the basics of MVVM, but certainly need practice to get a deeper understanding.

It seems like the [Orchestra](https://github.com/WildGums/Orchestra) Shell written on top of Catel is a good way to start a new application as it has many built-in features including an MVVM framework.

The WPF application I'm interested in developing is a utility to help with administration (viewing logs, checking service status, etc) of a specific enterprise application and would include:

- Fluent Ribbon
- Avalon Docking
- Ability for other developers to write plugins

As a WPF/MVVM novice, I'm having difficulty understanding the best way to get going with Orchestra, and it seems as though the [getting started guide](https://github.com/WildGums/Orchestra/blob/develop/doc/getting%20started/GettingStarted.md) included in the docs folder on github is a bit outdated.

The examples provided as well as the LogViewer application are great, but I could really use some pointers with getting started.  Does anyone know of an up-to-date getting started document for Orchestra, or would anyone be willing to provide some high-level steps?

Here are my preliminary thoughts on the steps required, but I'm not sure if this is the right approach:

1. Create a blank WPF project
2. Install Orchestra FluentRibbon using NuGet
3. Create a main view that contains the fluent ribbon
4. Create Prism Modules? for each component to be added to the
   application

   Example of components (Prism Modules?):

   - Connect/disconnect to application server
   - Load/show plugins

Any help/guidance would be appreciated -- perhaps starting w/ Orchestra is just not a good idea for a WPF/MVVM novice like me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Usually when starting something new, keeping things simple is the best choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to start is to take a look at the examples that are included in the Orchestra repository. For example, the [Fluent Ribbon examples](https://github.com/WildGums/Orchestra/tree/develop/src/Examples/Orchestra.Examples.Ribbon.Fluent) gives you an idea how to implement the ShellService.

After that, if you are looking for modularity with Catel and Prism, I recommend that you take a look at the [Catel examples repository](https://github.com/catel/catel.examples).

If you have more direct questions, feel free to chat with the team of any of the components using gitter.

Comment: Thanks for the very quick response!  I have been looking at the examples, but not really sure where to start from a process perspective.  Is the below process the correct approach when starting a new application w/ Orchestra?  Thanks again!

1. Create a blank WPF project Install Orchestra FluentRibbon using NuGet 2. Create a main view that contains the fluent ribbon
3. Create Prism Modules? for each component to be added to the application

Example of components (Prism Modules?):
•Connect/disconnect to application server
•Load/show plugins

Comment: Prism modules are a different kind of thing. Start without modules (and directly reference the other assemblies for now). They are easily to split up at a later stage once you have the shell working (as long as you put them into a separate assembly).

Comment: That makes sense.  Just a future suggestion: it would be terrific if there was either a getting started guide available or a document/blog containing a walkthrough of the different components within the examples.  However, your responses have been very helpful, so thanks again.